# What php function could I use to restrict access to the post page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I know wordpress says it can't be done, but I also understand that this can't be true. I'm trying to restrict access to the post page to logged in users only. I have tried plugins, but no luck. There has to be a way to no allow unregistered users to view this page. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons you may decide to restrict some content on your website from being viewed by the public. Whether it is to have user accounts, content for sale, or confidential data, you can use this method to house all your content in one place, thus allowing you to grant permission to those you choose to view it.

Top reasons to restrict access to a particular website might include:

```
User Accounts
Confidential Data
Personal Data
Digital Goods For Sale ( Books, Tutorials, Movies, Music)
Pro Rated Services
Pro Rated Media
Addons
```

An example of restricted access is lynda.com.

**Download the Restrict Content Plugin**

I’ll be using the [Restrict Content plugi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-content/)n by pippinsplugins to get things started off. Head to your WordPress Admin area and add the plugin. I searched Restrict Content and it was the first plugin on the list. Download it and activate it.

Next head to the Settings area in the left navigation. Look for the newly added link titled Restrict Content.

Inside the Restrict Content Settings panel are input fields where you can enter in message which displays if users try to access areas in which they are not allowed.

If you’re following along, enter the message below:

Restricted Message – We’re sorry. You do not have permission to access this page. Please sign up to be granted access.

All the rest – Just add the same message above for each tier of user role.
If you plan on having multiple user roles on your site, feel free to fill these in where needed.

Lets create a page that will have some content we don’t want to be accessible unless it’s for users with accounts on our site. I’ll call the page Books.

The intent would be to have books available for download to those with access to the page. The books will be digital downloads that are free for those who have been granted permission.

With the Books page created, I’ll add the content below. Navigate to the new page and notice the new block below the text area titled Restrict this content.

[check link here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-restrict-access-to-areas-of-your-wordpress-website)

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter what restrict content plugin I use, I am unable to restrict the "Post" page. Thanks anyways.

Comment: if you want to write you own code then set metakeys and check is it set or not before post page load.....ie in post.php.... i think it will help you

Comment: Restrict Content Plugin is working in same way....use [protected]My protected content![/protected] tag

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility of any post to be public, password protected or private. The last two options can assist

see this link for help https://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Visibility

Note also, toward the end of this page there is a note giving another method by using .htaccess to restrict who can visit your web site.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the solution I'm looking for. I will just have to figure out something else. Thanks.